# Does the word “Loyal” have other meaning than “remaining faithful to somebody/something and supporting them or it?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I found the following definition in the answer to “What are pimps and hoes?” in Music Genres Questions in Wiki.answer.com.:

> “A pimp is a *loyal* person who pimps out girls of so called hoes
>   meaning he makes them go have sex with guys for money and if the hoe
>   doesn’t listen she will get slapped or backhanded. Practically the
>   pimp makes the profit.”

I don’t understand the meaning of “a *loyal person* who pimp out girls,” as I recognized “loyal” only in the meaning of “being faithful to sb or sth.”

OALED at hand defines “loyal” simply as “remaining faithful to sb / sth and supporting them or it” with no mention on any other meanings.

Does the word, “*loyal*” have other meaning than being faithful to, for instance, “professional”?  If “Yes,” is it a customary usage of "loyal"?

Comment: This looks like an error. There is no mainstream definition of _loyal_ that means anything other than _being faithful_. If your quoted excerpt is slang usage, it is very localised.

Comment: I consulted with other dictionaries. Cambridge Dictionary defines “loyal” as ‘firm in your friendship with or support for a person or an organization, or in your belief in your principles.” Oxford Dictionary as “giving or showing firm and constant support or allegiance to a person or institution.” Only Readers English Japanese Dictionary published by Japanese dictionary specialist publisher mentions “2. Authorized (approved) by law" as an obsolete usage aside "1. faithful to sb. sth." I wonder if the writer of the quoted answer has used “loyal” in the “galapagosic” sense of “legally admitted.”

Comment: @coleopterist -- maybe submit that as an answer instead of a comment so it can be accepted or voted up and this question won't show up as "unanswered" any more?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with coleopterist that this is an error; but the interesting question remains: What did the author of this post *mean* by characterizing a pimp as ‘loyal’?

I can’t credit the UD definition offered by MonsterMushroom, which strikes me as a promotion for or tongue-in-cheek appreciation of one of several bands called “The Loyals” or with “Loyal” in their name.

I suspect the author is harkening back to a fairly well-known piece from the gangsta rap genre, “Loyal to the Game”, the title song (represented by two mixes) from a Tupac Shakur album posthumously released in 2004. The singer represents himself as a long-time, hardened criminal who supports his family and his extravagant lifestyle by violence, who fears no one and defies both the authorities and his rivals, and who demands respect for the identity he has achieved: “the struggle that I'm from is attached to my name”.

> I do my thing respect my hustle I ain't playin'  (Nigga I'm **loyal** to the game)
> You get in my way and I cock and pop that thing  (Man I'm **loyal** to the game)
> If you know what I know then you know I ain't playin'  (I'm **loyal** to the game)
> Nigga get in my way and I’ll blow out your brain

The tracks are available on YouTube, and full lyrics may be read [here](http://www.metrolyrics.com/loyal-to-the-game-lyrics-2pac.html).

I suggest that the author means readers to understand *loyal* as something like “a ‘made’ man, swaggeringly proud of his amorality”.

It is possible, too, that the use here is colored by chat around the popular online game *Pimp War*, in which players undertake the role of Pimp. The Pimp is depicted as very like 2Pac’s hero— fundamentally a loner, seeking to achieve invulnerability in a viciously Darwinian underworld—but to reach the top must form alliances with other Pimps. Loyalty to one’s partners (or at least the appearance of loyalty) is essential to building these alliances, as may be seen from the appeals:

> If you pimp daily, experienced, and loyal to your fellow alliance members message me or Frog(#2154) and after we check your stats we'll send you a invite.
>
> I ROLL WIT ALOT OF GOOD CREWS ILL ROLL WIT ANYONE REALLY THAT HAS SUMTHIN GOOD GOIN ECXEPT IN CRACKO I AM A TRU LOYAL CANADIAN-PIMP NO MATTA WHAT BUT IF U NEED ARMS IN ANOTHER GAME HALLA AT YA BOY 1

So *loyal* also implies “worthy of alliance”.

Comment: From Dickens to food service operations to Tupac Shakur's posthumous album, you've been churning out a bewildering array of answers today :) +1

Answer (score 0):

My money is that this is a typo, possibly for "low-life".

Answer (score 0):

Obviously OP's writer has what many of us would call "limited command of English". He's also probably not a very coherent thinker, so we can't expect too much here.

All he means is that (in his opinion, at least) the relationship between pimp and "hoe" is normally based on the whore being loyal to the pimp (or she'll get "slapped"). I'm no expert on the subject, but I imagine lots of pimps think they're loyal to their whores (they defend them robustly against violent/non-paying customers, etc.). So they're in a mutually loyal relationship, if you want to look at it that way.

Of course, the writer's concept of what exactly "loyalty" is might well be pretty fuzzy.

Answer (score -1):

When I read this, it sounded a lot like slang, along the lines of that's ill, she's bad, etc.  So, I went to my friend urbandictionary.com, and indeed the second definition of loyal

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=loyal

is noun: a god among mere men (this is an abbreviation of a very long definition) and adverb: mindbogglingly fabulous.

Given that your snippet is from the definition of a pimp, in a music context, I think the urbandictionary definition is the one you need.

I wouldn't start using it in conversation unless you're younger than twenty.